# How do I set priority of which application opens a url schema (rdp://) in kde?

Tags: kde, mime-types, settings, url, xdg

I have several applications installed that handles url schema `rdp://` (for example, rdp://myadmin@1.2.3.4). These applications are Krdc and Remmina. I want such links to be opened in krdc, but they are opened in remmina. I do not want to uninstall remmina. But when I uninstall it, then krdc is opening such links.

In kde settings under Applications there are Default Applications, but unfortunately it only contains several types of them (web browser, file browser, mailer, terminal).

Also, under applications there is File Associations. If I search "rdp" there, I only see related application/x-remmina, but there is no krdc.

How do I set krdc as a handler for rdp:// protocol in kde settings?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if that is on purpose, but in kde settings I cannot see the mime types for them. I mean, I can add a new one, but initially there is no one. However, applications are apparently somehow sorted.

I have found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591617/how-to-set-mime-priority-for-applications) question, that helped to achieve what I want.

First, in /usr/share/applications find the .desktop file for krdc and see for MimeType line. You see that the mime type is `x-scheme-handler/rdp`. Now we can query the sorter.

When krdc installed alone:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/rdp
org.kde.krdc.desktop
```

When remmina installed in parallel with krdc:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/rdp
org.remmina.Remmina.desktop
```

Take that name of .desktop file for the next command. After I run

```
$ xdg-mime default org.kde.krdc.desktop x-scheme-handler/rdp
```

I can query again and see that it is now krdc. Now when I click rdp:// links, they are opened in krdc.

P.S. Despite I achieved the task, I am still interested the "gui" way and why  there is no initially x-scheme-handler in File Associations. Comments are welcome.